# Spring WebServiceTemplate not giving back full response

Tags: spring, response, webservicetemplate

I am using Spring WebServiceTemplate MarshalSendAndReceive to make a web service call.
However the response I receive back from the call is missing most of the response that is sent from the web service.

When MarshalSendAndReceive runs I see a debug statement (not sure which exact class is generating this) but it displays both the full response and the request.

```
DEBUG:MessageTracing.received:Received response [<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ etc....
```

And this shows the full response:

```
<element1><element2><element3>etc..</element3></element2></element1>
```

However the response I receive back from MarshalSendAndReceive only contains element1 and element 2. Element3 or subsequent elements are not in the response.

Anybody have any idea why this might happen?

Thanks,

Kenny

Comment: Can you please include a little more information on what java class is it unmarshalling this xml to, and some more of the xml also, it is possible that the xml is probably not compliant in some way with the java type

Comment: I sort of purposely left out the xml and the java class(es) as the java is generated from a 30,000 line wsdl which generates about 1,000 java classes!
Is there any way I can see what is happening within the WebServiceTemplate to see why not all the xml (which looks absoultely fine in the debug statement) is not making it into the response? Thanks.